# Core Data Update not working

Tags: swift, core-data

My Core Data Save, Retrieve, and Delete are all working, but my Update is not working at all. Here is my code:

```
init() {
    appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
}

/**
 * Updates team in Core Data
 *
 * - parameter team: the Team to update
 */
func updateTeam(team: Team) {
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Team")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "city = %@", team.getCity())

    do {
        if let fetchResults = try self.managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as? [NSManagedObject] {
            if fetchResults.count != 0 {
                let managedObject = fetchResults[0]
                managedObject.setValue(team.getCity(), forKey: "city")
                managedObject.setValue(team.getMascot(), forKey: "mascot")
                managedObject.setValue(team.getOwner(), forKey: "owner")
                managedObject.setValue(team.getManager(), forKey: "manager")
                managedObject.setValue(team.getSeasonWins(), forKey: "seasonWins")
                managedObject.setValue(team.getSeasonLosses(), forKey: "seasonLosses")
                managedObject.setValue(team.getCareerWins(), forKey: "careerWins")
                managedObject.setValue(team.getCareerLosses(), forKey: "careerLosses")

                try self.managedContext.save()
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error updating user team")
    }
}
```

I can save the initial team data, retrieve the team data, and delete the team data, but when I try to update the team (code above), is not reflected in the following retrieval.

Comment: Have you stepped through this code in the debugger? Why are you fetching a team when you're passing a team into the method in the first place? Why do you have all of these getCity() functions instead of accessing the properties of the team directly?

Comment: Well for updating, you would have already had a Team retrieved. So, when you want to update, you would pass the modified Team back in, grab the old team in the database (by providing the predicate 'city = team.getCity()' since the city never changes), and then updating the managedObject with the new Team data. Does that sound right?

Comment: @LoganJahnke No need to refetch.  Assuming the `city` is unique, `managedObject` and `team` are the self same object (CoreData ensures uniqueness - a single object from the store will have only one instance in the managedObjectContext).  Hence you are getting the values of the attributes and assigning them to the same attributes of the same object.

Comment: So even if team has been modified, the Core Data version will be the same object when using the unique city name? Why is that?

Comment: That's how core data works. It's called _uniquing_.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the `Transient` attribute (for your all keys) is not check in your `.xcdatamodel`

[image: Transient attribute]

Comment: If saving and retrieving data is working, as the questioner says, how can this be the problem?

Comment: He said that he can't modify data. I'm just wondering if this attribute block him (cause this one blocked me in a project)

Comment: Transient attributes would not be saved or retrieved.

Comment: Oh ok... I understand now.. I wasn't sure the the transient attribute don't retrieve data ...